# find the inverse of $\frac{1-e^t}{1+e^t}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, inverse

Hi I am trying to prove that the inverse of $f(t) = \frac{1-e^t}{1+e^t}$ is 
$F^{-1}(t) = \ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t} \right )$

But I don't quite know where to start? 
Do I just sub $\frac{1-e^t}{1+e^t}$ for all t in $F^{-1}(t) = \ln \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t} \right)$?

Comment: Think of $x=e^t$ as the other variable. Can you solve $x$ from
$$y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}?$$ When you are done with that, then solve $t$.

Answer (score 2):

From the original equation, we want to solve for $t$ in terms of $y=f(t)$.

$\displaystyle y = \frac{1-e^t}{1+e^t} $

$\displaystyle (1+e^t)y = 1-e^t$

$\displaystyle y + ye^t = 1 - e^t$ (*)

$(1+y)e^t = 1-y$   $\quad$ (grouping $e^t$ terms together, attempting to solve for $e^t$)

$\displaystyle e^t = \frac{1-y}{1+y}$

I can divide by $1+y$ because $y\neq-1$. You can plug $y=-1$ into the original equation and has no solution.

Now you can take the natural logarithm on both sides, switch y and t, and obtain the desired result.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @dh87.I thought of doing this but got stuck at taking the 1+e^t to the other side. What do you mean by grouping e^t terms?

Comment: I added a line (*) to help you understand. What I meant is to distribute $y$, and group terms with $e^t$ to the left side, and the remaining terms to the right side. I'm sorry I did a little fast.

Comment: Ok thanks @dh87 I think I get it now. so ye^t + e^t becomes (1+y)e^t.